# WP Query filter search. Result show all posts instead just custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have some weird situation. I created CPT and made wp query to list all posts on a page. Later I made a search by keyword, month and year. month and year search working fine, but when I enter a keyword, wp show me all posts instead just custom post type posts. Prob I miss something but I can't find a solution, so I need help from you people.

```
$obj_id = get_queried_object_id();
$current_url = get_permalink( $obj_id );

$script = ( get_query_var('script') ? sanitize_text_field(get_query_var('script')) : '' );

$filter['q'] = ( get_query_var('q') ? sanitize_text_field(get_query_var('q')) : '' );
$filter['godina'] = ( get_query_var('godina') ? sanitize_text_field(get_query_var('godina')) : '' );
$filter['mesec'] = ( get_query_var('mesec') ? sanitize_text_field(get_query_var('mesec')) : '' );

    $years_list = get_years_list();
    $months_list = get_months_list();

    <form action="<?php echo esc_url($current_url); ?>" method="get" id="gallery-filters">
        <?php if (!empty($script)) : ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="script" value="<?php echo $script; ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>

        <input type="text" name="q" value="<?php echo $filter['q']; ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Pretraži', 'html5blank' ); ?>">

        <select name="godina">
            <option value=""><?php esc_html_e( 'Godina', 'html5blank' ); ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($years_list as $year_val) : $year_val = trim($year_val); ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $year_val; ?>" <?php echo ($year_val == $filter['godina'] ? 'selected' : ''); ?>><?php echo $year_val; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>

        <select name="mesec">
            <option value=""><?php esc_html_e( 'Mesec', 'html5blank' ); ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($months_list as $month_num => $month_val) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $month_num; ?>" <?php echo ($month_num == $filter['mesec'] ? 'selected' : ''); ?>><?php echo $month_val; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" name="" class="btn bordered" value="<?php esc_html_e( 'pretražite', 'html5blank' ); ?>">
    </form>

    <?php 
        // the query
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $args = array(
            'post_type'=>'gallery',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'posts_per_page'=> 9,
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        if (!empty($filter['q'])) {
            $args['s'] = $filter['q'];
        }

        if (!empty($filter['godina'])) {
            $args['year'] = $filter['godina'];
        }

        if (!empty($filter['mesec'])) {
            $args['monthnum'] = $filter['mesec'];
        }

        $all_posts = new WP_Query($args); ?>

        <?php if ( $all_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ( $all_posts->have_posts() ) : $all_posts->the_post(); ?>
                ...
```

Comment: Stefan It may be that your theme or something is interfering with the query.  There are some posts that may offer suggestions.  One is to use get_posts rather.   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35062/post-type-is-ignored-by-wp-query-when-tag-argument-is-included  and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts.

Comment: Hm...will read what are you suggesting. I never use get_posts in that way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found bug in theme, and that is searching just posts in all theme.

```
if (!is_admin()) {
    function wpb_search_filter($query) {
  if ($query->is_search) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'post');
  }
  return $query;
  }
  add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpb_search_filter');
}
```